# add new category to Applications

Tags: desktop, elementary-os, pantheon, slingshot-launcher

I'm using elementary os luna.

How can i add a new category to the Applications menu !?[image: Applications menu (Elementary OS luna]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Add new category to pantheon applications menu :

Finally i found a way to do it.

**First:** create .directory file in **/usr/share/desktop-directories/**

and type these lines

Example /usr/share/desktop-directories/****.directory:  (replace **** with the filename )

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Directory
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=????
```

(replace ???? with the new Category Name)

**Then :** add these lines to **/etc/xdg/menus/pantheon-applications.menu**

```
<Menu>
 <Name>????</Name>
 <Directory>****.directory</Directory>
 <Include>
   <And>
     <Category>????</Category>
   </And>
 </Include>
</Menu>
```

**finally :** edit **/usr/share/applications/** app.desktop (replace app with the application name you want to add to the new category) and  type Categories=????;...;...(other categories);

Answer (score 0):

since Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, maybe Alacarte is something for you.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alacarte

http://elementaryos.org/answers/how-do-i-use-alacarte-with-elementary-os-1

Comment: thank you for help, but that didn't work :(